# Undefined AJAX Laravel 5.2 Message

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

My problem is not work AJAX Laravel For me in ver5.2 how to solve this problem 
my error:

> Route [category] not defined. (View: C:\wamp\www\pc\resources\views\admin\category.blade.php)

my Route file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('category', 'categoryController@index');
});
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::post('category', 'categoryController@create');
});
```

my controller:

```
public function create(messageRequest $request)
{
    try {
        Category::create($request->all());
        return response()->json(array('sms'=>'save Success'));
    }catch (Exception $e){
        return response()->json(array('err'=>'error'));
    }
}
```

my javascript:

```
<script>
    $('#submit').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $('#create').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '{!! URL::route('category') !!}',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.sms);
                console.log('data');
            },
            error:function(){
                alert(data.err);
                console.log('data');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Route::post('category', 'categoryController@create');
```

change to

```
Route::post('category', ['as' => 'category',  'uses' => 'categoryController@create']);
```

Comment: You should explain *why* this is a solution: `URL::route('category')` looks for a **named** route, and OP didn't name their routes. `URL::to('category')` would also work for a non-named route.

Comment: true, URL::to would be an easier fix but naming routes generally seems like a good idea

Comment: Agreed entirely. I just wanted to elaborate on the difference.

Answer (score -1):

in view:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
});
```

> ```
> <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
> <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
> ```

in controller:

```
 /**
 * Determine if the session and input CSRF tokens match.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @return bool
 */
protected function tokensMatch($request)
{
    // If request is an ajax request, then check to see if token matches token provider in
    // the header. This way, we can use CSRF protection in ajax requests also.
    $token = $request->ajax() ? $request->header('X-CSRF-Token') : $request->input('_token');

    return $request->session()->token() == $token;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your posted question.